# Git - how to unmerge changes into a new branch?

Tags: git

Some time ago I merged branch X into master. I forgot when this was and git log now merged all the commits. How do I create a new branch with the version of master before X was merged into it?

Comment: Was it a fast-forward merge, or do you have a merge commit around?

Comment: I did `git checkout master && git merge X`

Comment: ...and do you have a merge commit?  That is, do you have some commit in master that says "merged branch X"?

Comment: I do but it's all a mess, since I worked on the new branch for over a year. Can't figure out at which point I ended work on master before merging.

Comment: Did you try to use `git log --merges` ?